# Scrapy terminated unexpected

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I follow  book published by o'Reilly to create a spider as below:
articleSpider.py

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from TestScrapy.items import Article
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ArticleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "article"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$'), ),callback="parse_item", follow=True)]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = Article()
        title =  response.xpath('//h1/text()')[0].extract()
        print "Title is:" + title
        item['title'] = title
        return item
```

Items.py

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class Article(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = Field()
```

However, when I run this spider, it just display one result and the terminates. I expect it to run until I terminate it.

Please see the result and debug info from Scrapy:

```
2016-06-06 15:45:28 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: TestScrapy)
2016-06-06 15:45:28 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-06-06 15:45:28 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'TestScrapy.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['TestScrapy.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'TestScrapy'}
2016-06-06 15:45:29 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-06 15:45:30 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-06-06 15:45:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming> (referer: None)
Title is:Object-oriented programming
2016-06-06 15:45:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming>
{'title': u'Object-oriented programming'}
2016-06-06 15:45:33 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-06 15:45:33 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 246,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 51238,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 6, 7, 45, 33, 441000),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 6, 7, 45, 30, 614000)}
2016-06-06 15:45:33 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method name from `parse` to `parse_item`.

Now you're just crawling the start url but when filtering the rules there is no method to callback, thus the spider ends the execution.

Check this example of CrawlSpider:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example

Comment: Indeed,`parse` method is special for `CrawlSpider` (see [the warning here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#crawling-rules))

Comment: Thank you so much. Javitronxo and Paul. It addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `start_product_requests` instead of `parse` here.